# iphone string replace only the first occurrence with another string

Tags: iphone, string, replace

I have a string in iphone that looks like the following one:

```
    my.whatever.string.with.unknown.length=something whatever something = something .... = whatever
```

I want to replace only the FIRST "=" with something else.

If I use :

```
    [myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"=" withString:@"somethingHere" ];
```

It will replace all occurences of "=" . Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the range argument to specify how far into the string you want it to search. Assuming you can find where the first `=` is, you can use that to do it. The method definition looks like this:

```
replaceOccurrencesOfString:withString:options:range:
```

Comment: this is the full answer!! Thanks...


myString = [myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"=" withString:@"replaceWithThis" options:NSLiteralSearch range:[line rangeOfString:@"="]];

Comment: @Panos solution works great. Just FYI for new readers, `line` is actually `myString`.

Answer (score -4):

You can replace string like this..

```
 NSString *mystring=FIRST;
 NSString *trimmedString = [mystring stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
```

Comment: Did you read my question????  I have explicitly said that this replaces ALL occurrences. I want only the first one.